# If I delete the pod data in etcd, what will happen in kubelet?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

If I stop the Apiserver and delete a pod data in etcd, then I restart the Apiserver.

What will happen in kubelet and if the kubelet will delete the real pod?

Comment: Probably? But it's not exactly a tested scenario so try it out and see. Also why would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer.

You cannot stop Apiserver.

If you remove the pod it will be rescheduled, so you would need to remove the `kube-apiserver.yaml` from `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` first.

If you do that you won't be able to edit etcd.

> **Etcd** is an open-source distributed key-value store that serves as the backbone of distributed systems by providing a canonical hub for cluster coordination and state management – the systems source of truth.

You can edit values manually by going into etcd pod and changing the data, but this is a bit problematic.

Or you can use `etcdctl` tool.

> `etcdctl` is a command line client for [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd). It can be used in scripts or for administrators to explore an etcd cluster.

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://[127.0.0.1]:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki
/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key
```